# PHP / SimpleXML - Get attribute value based on attribute name

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I'm using SimpleXMLElement like so:

```
$visitor_body = wp_remote_retrieve_body( $url );
$visitor_data = new SimpleXMLElement( $visitor_body );
```

I have the following XML structure response:

```
<resultSet>
  <aggregates>
     <metric name="visitDuration" value="488" label="Avg. Visit Duration"/>
     <metric name="uniqueVisitors" value="8" label="Unique Visitors"/>
     <metric name="visits" value="14" label="Visits"/>
     <metric name="pageViews" value="35" label="Page Views"/>
     <metric name="bounceRate" value="0.5" label="Bounce Rate"/>
     <metric name="pagesPerVisit" value="2.5" label="Pages Per Visit"/>
  </aggregates>
```

I need to get the value for `visitDuration` `uniqueVisitors` `visits` and so on in way that I can use in various places. For instance, within a variable such as:

```
echo $visitDuration;
echo $uniqueVisitors;
```

Comment: Did you had some simple research for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php - this page is where you need to research.

or how about this?

http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/

```
* A HTML DOM parser written in PHP5+ let you manipulate HTML in a very easy way!
* Require PHP 5+.
* Supports invalid HTML.
* Find tags on an HTML page with selectors just like jQuery.
* Extract contents from HTML in a single line.

// Find all visitDuration
foreach($html->find('visitDuration') as $element)
       echo $element->value. '<br>'; // returns 488

// Find all bounceRate
foreach($html->find('bounceRate') as $element)
       echo $element->value. '<br>'; // returns 0.5
```

Comment: Thanks @Prakash, that worked great! I also found this to work as well: `$visitDuration = $visitor_data->aggregates->metric[0]['value'];echo $visitDuration;`